# broke my ipod touch sleep button?

Tags: ipod-touch

I broke my sleep button on my iPod touch so I cannot use the button to shut down and turn it back on... If I let it die, will it turn on by itself if I plug it into a charger?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Your device will boot automatically when connected to a power source (like your computer usb or a charger).

You can simulate the power button using Assistive Touch. You can find assistive touch in:
`Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> AssistiveTouch`
It might be obvious Assistive Touch can only be accessed when your device is on (even from the lock screen).

Comment: Assistive Touch: Apple's watered-down version of Activator that I wish would just become Activator.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson, what is Activator? Do you need to jailbreak your phone to install Activator?

Comment: Activator allows you to assign actions to all sorts of system events such as gestures and hardware button presses, and yes, you do need to be jailbroken in order to install it.